# How do I check for duplicates when making a map?

Tags: java, maps

If I was given a list of String (sentences) and for each sentence, I am supposed to put every first word as the key of a map while the remaining words are values (`String[]`). How do I check that no two first words are the same? I actually have no idea how to go about this. Any help I will appreciate.

For example:

"Hello, my name is John"

"the dog is fat"

"My pen is broken"

```
map.put("hello", String[]);
```

---> `string[]` means the rest of words in sentence.

```
map.put("the", String[]);

map.put("My", string[]);
```

All I want to do is put a restriction and that restriction is if two of the first words are the same, I should throw IllegalArgumentException. Thank you!

Comment: `map.containsKey(key)` would do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, String[] > map . . . ;
if( map.containsKey(yourKey) ) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-unique key! key = " + yourKey);
} else {
  map.put(yourKey,value);
}
```